# RenderView in Symfony Helper usage

Tags: symfony, render, symfony-3.4

How can I use `$this->renderView` inside a Symfony helper class (not inside a controller)?
I'm new about the function `renderView` but what do I have to setup to use it within the `Helper` class?

Comment: Why do you want to render outside of controller ? what's the reason ?

Comment: Actually i have two controller classes which uses almost the same code to genarte pdfs. To remove same code in multiple places I have been suggested to add a common helper class and use it in both the controllers.

Comment: Okay, you can still group some code and return specific variables you need then use then in render function.

Comment: yeah i get it, but is there any other way because i have many renderview functions and i do not want to have same code in both the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject twig as a service with autowiring

```
<?php

namespace App\My\Ns;

use Twig\Environment;

class Helper
{
    public function __construct(
        protected Environment $environment
    ) {
    }

    public function method()
    {
        $html = $this->environment->render('my/template.html.twig', [/*  vars */]);
    }
}
```